# Lie derivative of the partial derivative of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, covariance

I am currently studying this metric 'object'

$$g_{\mu \nu}\partial_\rho g^{\rho \mu} \partial_\sigma g^{\sigma \nu}$$

which is clearly not a tensor. I want to compute the Lie derivative.

My problem is that i don't know how to compute the Lie derivative of the partial derivative of the metric

$$ \mathcal{L}_{\xi} \left[\partial_\rho g^{\mu \nu}\right] $$

Either in a covariant or an contravariant form. There's a formula that connects derivatives of both cases, so one of them would be enough.

This is not a tensor, even a tensor density so i can't use the general formula for these cases. I can't relate this object to the Christoffel symbols with this particular index arrange, so i can't use the well-known formula for $\mathcal{L}_\xi \Gamma^\rho_{\mu \nu}$. I don't know if this even exists or make sense.

Any tips?

Comment: You can do this by hand by considering an infinitesimal coordinate transformation on both objects. Another option (though I doubt any easier) would be to simply rewrite the partial derivative of the metric term as two Christoffel symbol terms: then everything is in terms of your standard Lie derivative formulae.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't think of rewritting in term of Christoffel symbols (i thought that was no relation for this index arrangement). I'm going to show in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Eletie comment, i found a way to rewrite this derivative as a combination of Christoffel symbols

$$\partial_\rho g^{\mu \nu} = -(g^{\mu \lambda}\Gamma^\nu_{\rho \lambda} + g^{\nu \lambda}\Gamma^\mu_{\rho \lambda})$$

And now, using Leibniz's rule of the Lie derivative and the Lie derivative of the connection coefficients, i have found what i was looking for. If you are interested i end up with this expression

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}_\xi (\partial_\rho g^{\mu \nu}) = \Gamma^\nu_{\rho \lambda}\xi^{(\mu ; \lambda)} - g^{\mu \lambda}(\xi^\nu_{;\rho \lambda} - R^\nu_{\rho \lambda \sigma}\xi^\sigma) + \Gamma^\mu_{\rho \lambda}\xi^{(\nu ; \lambda)} - g^{\nu \lambda}(\xi^\mu_{; \rho \lambda} - R^\mu_{\rho \lambda \sigma}\xi^\sigma)
\end{equation}

Comment: Cool!  Does your formula for the Lie derivative of the Christffel symbol agree with the one I found: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191468/.  I have worried that I have a sign differehce in the ast ter, from that in a paper by Zumino.

Comment: I used the formula in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2415759/ , so i writted in terms of the Riemmann tensor and the diffeomorphism vector field.